# Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, syntax-error, directory

I tring to check if a folder is empty but I keep getting this error

Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

```
if(!file_exists(glob('/upload/'.$id.'/temp/*'))){
$smeg = 'empty';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`glob`** returns an `array` type.

Change your code like this

```
foreach(glob('/upload/'.$id.'/temp/*') as $filename)
{
    if(!file_exists($filename))
    {
       $smeg = 'empty';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the PHP doc about [`glob()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php):

> **Returns an array** containing the matched files/directories, an empty
>   array if no file matched or FALSE on error.

You have to loop over the result

```
foreach(glob('/upload/'.$id.'/temp/*') as $file) {
    if(!file_exists($file)){
        $smeg = 'empty';
    }
}
```